# How to pass arguments directly to default controller in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have one controller called **"site"** which is a default controller. I want to display all the post from my database. So whenever users go to my site, they can see all the posts. I have removed **"index.php"** and URL rewriting on through .htaccess.

There are two buttons called **latest** and **popular** and also some **categories** on that page. I just want whenever user click on **latest** or **popular** button or any **category** I want to pass the data directly to the default controller like this way-

```
http://example.com          //Show all post from all categories
http://example.com/latest   //Show the latest post from all categories
http://example.com/popular  // Show the popular posts from all categories

http://example.com/health          //Show all post from category health
http://example.com/health/latest   //Show latest post from category health
http://example.com/health/popular  //Show popular post from category health
```

Now my questing is how to write the routing part.
This is my default routing

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
```

and here is my index method of site controller

```
public function index($cat=null, $type=null)
{
    //The other logic here
}
```

Comment: How will you determine in http://example.com/latest that latest is a filter and in http://example.com/health , health is a category?

Comment: Yes I understand but, how to pass a single argument there? Do you have any idea?

Comment: You did right in index function. Just remove $type arguement